# unknown open ports/services 54409 and 16808

Tags: networking, router, port, services

I have a Linksys EA6400 router. Today, I have noticed in the log file some activity from multiple ip addresses on 2 ports that are open: **54409** and **16808** and I do not know what is going on there.

I did not open any ports manually and did no specific changes in the router settings.
All I am using is an external HDD that is connected to the router and can be accessed from the web via ftp.

Does anyone has any idea why are those ports open and what service uses them by default? Or how can I find that out?

The result of scanning my ip for ports:

PORT STATE SERVICE
21/tcp open ftp
16808/tcp open unknown
51000/tcp closed unknown
54409/tcp open unknown

Comment: It is likely that those ports are being used by internal clients as stateful connections through the NAT. that means that they are not "open ports" per se, but ports that are in use by an existing connections. Also, if the protocol is UDP, when a UDP socket is opened by NAT, it remains open for a window of time, so that responses can pass through. UDP is connectionless, so it can't rely on the stateful nature of NAT in the same way TCP can.

Comment: I have port scanned my ip address and the ports are constantly open. There are lots of ip addresses from all over the world (as I checked some are blacklisted) appearing in the Incoming connections log

Comment: what internal service are they connecting to?

Comment: the log of the router isn't too detailed. There are only 3 sections: Incoming log, Outgoing log and DHCP log. Inside the Incoming log I found lots of ip addresses with these two ports. This is what I would like to know, what is going on there. And why are these ports open on my router and what is their purpose?

Comment: well, generally, you would make note of the external servers, and go around to your clients, checking with netstat to see if any of them are connected to a given external IP,. and then check the service. an EA6400 is a Stateful Filtering device, so unless you have created port forward rules to allow an unsolicited port inbound, then a box on the LAN is soliciting the connection. in an elevated powershell you can check for a connection with `netstat -ab | findstr <externalIPAddress>`. this shoudl give you the PID of the process, which you can then look up in Process Explorer or Task Manager.

Comment: this looks nice. So You say that anything on my LAN can keep this port alive and open. A service or a virus as well. I will check this later. If this will help me figure out what is going on, I will ask You to write your comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: `netstat -ab` was enough to list my active connections, so I have found out that **54409** is skype.exe and **16808** is a torrent client. Thank You for the solution, please add your last comment as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your router performs Stateful Packet Inspection, there are three possible reasons to see "open" ports with traffic flows exiting the router:

1. You have the device set up in a DMZ, and all unsolicited traffic is
   directed to it,
2. You have created a port forwarding rule, that allows that port to be directed in bound to a specific system, for unsolicited traffic,
3. Or the port you are seeing is not actually open, but in use by an existing connection solicited from the LAN. The port will not accept
   unsolicited traffic, but is accessible to TCP connection hijacking
   attack attempts (though these are very hard to pull off these days).

If neither condition 1 or 2 is true, then the connection was made from inside your LAN.

Because you have limited log information, and (mostly) unmanaged network equipment, the easiest way to determine the LAN client and process, for a home network, would be to simply visit each terminal and determine whether the terminal is connected to a remote server on that port.

you can do this from an elevated powershell instance, with the command:

`netstat -abno | findstr <portnum>`

or if the remote IP is known:

`netstat -abno | findstr <RemoteIPAddr>`

From there, once you have found the client connection, you can note the Process ID, which you can then look up in Process Explorer or Task Manager, to determine the executable causing the connection.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a computer connected in the internal LAN, you can use it's NIC in promiscuous mode to capture packets coming from/going to those ports in question. You can use tcpdump or Wireshark to acomplish that. The output of this analysis should show you what in your internal network is using those connection and then investigate further.

Comment: Thank You for the answer, I have already got a solution to this from Frank Thomas. As soon as I will have enough reputation, I will rate this answer up as well, as an alternate solution.